# Nuxt : Property '$axios' does not exist on type '{ submit(): Promise<void>; }'

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js

Why am I getting the error below with  `npm run dev` when using `<script lang="ts">` instead of `<script>` in a Nuxt page and how can I fix it ?

```
 ERROR  ERROR in pages/contact.vue:172:18                                                                                    11:52:05
TS2339: Property '$axios' does not exist on type '{ submit(): Promise<void>; }'.
    170 |       // 
    171 |       // 
  > 172 |       await this.$axios
        |                  ^^^^^^
    173 |         .post('my-api/message', {
    175 |           body: 'Hello World!',
```

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2018",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "lib": ["ESNext", "ESNext.AsyncIterable", "DOM"],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "~/*": ["./*"],
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    },
    "types": [
      "@nuxt/types",
      "@nuxt/content",
      "@nuxtjs/axios",
      "@types/node",
      "@nuxtjs/vuetify"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules", ".nuxt", "dist"]
}
```

`package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@nuxt/content": "^1.14.0",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.1",
    "@nuxtjs/markdownit": "^2.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/recaptcha": "^1.0.3",
    "core-js": "^3.9.1",
    "html": "^1.0.0",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.3",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.24.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nuxt/types": "^2.15.3",
    "@nuxt/typescript-build": "^2.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/dotenv": "^1.4.1",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^6.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config-typescript": "^6.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.11.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^7.22.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^7.7.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

#### === EDIT ===

`pages/my-page.vue`

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="12" sm="7" md="6">
        <v-form ref="form" lazy-validation @submit.prevent="submit()">
          <v-textarea
            v-if="!messageSent"
            ref="body"
            v-model="body"
            clearable
            auto-grow
            outlined
          />
          <v-btn
            class="float-right"
            color="blue darken-1 white--text"
            type="submit"
          >
            SEND
          </v-btn>
        </v-form>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      body: null,
      messageSent: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async submit() {
      await this.$axios
        .post('my-api/message', {
          body: 'Hello World!'
        })
        .then((res: any) => {
          console.log(res)
        })
        .catch((err: any) => {
          console.log(err)
        })
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Well, post the content of `pages/contact.vue`.

Comment: @zhulien I have updated my post with the page